# Truncate table Sink Pre-copy script

Tags: azure-data-factory

So I am copying 10 different tables from Azure SQLDB to Azure SQLMI, I need to truncate the destination table before it inserts the data. But I am just cannot get to it work. BTW total n00b at Azure ADF.

I have tried a couple of different solutions in other threads but they just do not work for me.

Tried
TRUNCATE TABLE @item().destination.table
TRUNCATE TABLE [@{item().name}]

"Operation on target ForEach_Loop failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed; Inner activity name: Copy_Tables, Error: The expression 'item().name' cannot be evaluated because property 'name' doesn't exist, available properties are 'source, destination'."

Help please?

[image: ForEach Loop]

Comment: can you provide the array which you are giving to ForEach?

Comment: Based on the values that you have passed in dataset, you need to try truncate table @{item().destination.table}

assuming it contains schemaname.tablename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Operation on target ForEach_Loop failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed; Inner activity name: Copy_Tables, Error: The expression 'item().name' cannot be evaluated because property 'name' doesn't exist, available properties are 'source, destination'."

The error indicates that there are only `source` and `destination` keys for **every item** and the tablename must be inside the destination object.

And as per your dynamic content, your ForEach input array can be like this.

```
[ 
{ 
    "source": 
        { 
        "table": "Source1"
         }, 
     "destination": 
         { 
         "table": "Target1" 
         } 
 }, 
 {
     "source": 
         { 
         "table": "Source2" 
         }, 
     "destination": 
         { 
         "table": "Target2" 
         } 
 }, 
 {
     "source": 
         { 
         "table": "Source3" 
         }, 
     "destination": 
         { 
         "table": "Target3" 
         } 
 }
 ]
```

So, give the Truncate query in the pre-copy script using string interpolation  `Truncate table @{item().destination.table}` as suggested by **@Nandan** in comments.

This is my sample Example using a copy activity.

[image]

You can see the script here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rakesh & Nandan, htat did it, I was missing the braces around my statement.